# unity movement, object keeps falling even when key is held down

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm still new to unity and I'm trying to create controls for a hot air balloon, however even though I'm still holding down the up arrow the object ends up falling after a few seconds and I'm not sure why.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
           
           transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
           fuel = fuel - 3 * Time.deltaTime;
           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that the object is "falling" I take that to mean that you've added a `Rigidbody` (or `Rigidbody2D`) component to it with gravity enabled.

If you're using a `Rigidbody` to simulate gravity, you can't just manually manipulate the position like this. You'll want to use [Rigidbody.AddForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) instead.

Comment: Did some research into it and managed to get it working, thank you.